# In Flutter what is the best way to back up shared preferences key value pair pair to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, sharedpreferences

I use the sharedprefrences package in flutter which works fine locally.

But every time I uninstall and reinstall the app the data does not recover. So I would like to backup the data in firebase.

What is the best way to do so if I want to back up data with an onpressed function?

Comment: Firestore seems to handle JSON very well (with the exception of DateTime, which is turned into Timestamp). You could try to store "settings" as a JSON object in the SharedPreferences. This can be stored into a document in Firestore very easily, given that it doesn't exceed 2MB